# Inconsistent output from get_image_features() in BLIP model—how to get consistent results?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, huggingface

I am currently using the BLIP model to get image embeddings via its get_image_features() method. However, every time I reload the model, this method returns different values for the same input. Is there a way to obtain consistent results each time the model is loaded?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is my code snippet.

```py
from PIL import Image
from transformers import AutoProcessor, TFBlipModel
model = TFBlipModel.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")

image = Image.open(img_path)
inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="tf")
image_features = model.get_image_features(**inputs).numpy().squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's because of the seed used for the model. You should be able to set a defined seed for a consistent response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Could you please provide a short code snippet as an example? Any example related to Transformers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way in my case.
This is my code snippet.

You need to save and load the weights of the model.

```py
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AutoProcessor, TFBlipModel

model = TFBlipModel.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")
# model.save_weights("weights", save_format="tf")
model.load_weights("weights")
processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-base")

image = Image.open("./abc.jpg")
inputs = processor(images=image, return-tensors="tf")
image_features = model.get_image_features(**inputs).numpy().squeeze()
print(image_features)
```

First you have to save the wegiths, then load the weights.